# DataContractSerializer with Multi-tiered data structures

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm attempting to implement a `DataContractSerializer` to generate an XML file that represents our somewhat complicated object model.  The root object has multiple `ICollection` properties, one of which has multiple `ICollection` properties, multiples of which have multiple `ICollection` properties... you get the idea.

I decorated all my relevant classes with `[DataContract(Name = "foo")]` tags, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319116/include-vs-load-performance-in-entityframework) question about using `Include()`, and started framing it out.  As I put together the top layer, I wondered if the second layer would need explicit declarations as well.  Here's what I have so far:

```
    public void Serialize(string DataCode)
    {
        Product prod = context.Products
            .Include(p => p.Products)
            .Include(p => p.References)
            .Include(p => p.Dates)
            .Include(p => p.Weights)
            .Include(p => p.Notes)
            .Include(p => p.Rules)  // Rules have PriceConditions, which have Prices...
            .Include(p => p.DataBooks)
            .First(m => m.ProductCode == DataCode);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Create);
        XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(fs);
        DataContractSerializer serializer =  new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Product));
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, prod);
    }
```

So, do I need to do something with Rules in order to ensure that the entire structure gets written, or does `Include()` know to tunnel deep into the structure and load each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to explicitly include the lower levels as well.

```
Product prod = context.Products
    .Include(p => p.Rules.Select(r => r.PriceConditions.Select(p => p.Prices)));
```

- [Serialize Entity Framework object with children to XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234290/serialize-entity-framework-object-with-children-to-xml-file)
- [MSDN page on Include() with examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx#remarksToggle)

Comment: What if you don't know how many levels down the structure goes?

Comment: I tried looking around, but it seems like you'd have to explicitly `Include()` each property at some point. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512285/entity-framework-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-eager-load-child-entities-wit. Maybe you could ask another question about eager loading all children at specific points.